# Load custom properties file in Spring Boot MVC Main

Tags: spring-boot

I have created a myApp.properties in resources folder location and mentioned the server.port in this file.

**myApp.properties**

```
myApp.server.port=8020
```

Now I want to read load this property into my application. But I have to read this before I actually a server.

Here I am trying to do like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myorg.myapp" })
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:myApp.properties")
@Component
public class MyAppApplication {

    @Value("${myApp.server.port}")
    private static String serverPort;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        try {

            SpringApplication appCtxt = new SpringApplication(MyAppApplication.class);
            appCtxt.setDefaultProperties(Collections
                    .singletonMap("server.port", serverPort));

            appCtxt.run(args);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But `serverPort` is coming as `null`.

I also tried to create a separate Config file like this but it can't be accessed in `static main`

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("myApp.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties

public class MyAppConfig {

    @Value("${myApp.server.port}")
    private String serverPort;

    /**
     * @return the serverPort
     */
    public String getServerPort() {
        return serverPort;
    }

}
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot injects properties during the initialization of the application context.
This happens (gets triggered) in the line:

```
appCtxt.run(args);
```

But you try to access the property **before** this line - that why it doesn't work.

So bottom line, using "@Value" in the main method doesn't work and it shouldn't.

Now from the code snippet, it looks like you could merely follow the "standards" of spring boot and create the file `application.properties` with:

```
server.port=1234
```

The process of starting the embedded web server in spring boot honors this property and bottom line it will have the same effect and Tomcat will be started on port 1234

**Update 1**

Based on OP's comment:

> So, how can I have multiple application.properties.

In the [Spring Boot's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) it is written that `application.properties` are resolved from the classpath. So you can try the following assuming you have different modules A,B,C and web app D:

- Create  `src/main/resources/application.properties` inside each of 4 modules and pack everything together. The configuration values will be merged (hopefully they won't clash)
- If you insist on naming properties A.properties, B.properties and C.properties for each of non-web modules, you can do the following (I'll show for module A, but B and C can do the same).

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:A.properties")
public class AConfiguration {

}
```

Create in Module A: `src/main/resources/A.properties`

If you need to load the AConfiguration automatically - make the module A starter (using autoconfig feature of spring-boot):

Create `src/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` file with the following content:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
<package_of_AConfiguration>.AConfiguration
```

> Also this has been the requirement to separate C from entire bundle where it might run as bundle for some and as a separate for some others

Although I haven't totally understood the requirement, but you can use `@ConditionalOnProperty` for configuration `CConfiguration` (that will be created just like `AConfiguration.java` in my previous example) but this times for module C.

If the conditional is met, configuration will run and load some beans / load its own properties or whatever. All in all conditionals (and in particular Profiles in spring) can help to reach the desired flexibility.

Comment: Thanks Mark for suggestion. But the structure of my application is Parent POM based where I have 4 children of parent. 3 of those are child having their own properties like A.properties, B.properties, C.properties and child D is a web application which is having application.properties. So, how can I have multiple application.properties. Also this has been the requirement to separate C from entire bundle where it might run as bundle for some and as a separate for some others.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, if all are working as separate services then it is fine to have one application.properties against each.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `application.properties` file can be used to store property pairs, though you can also define any number of additional property files.

If you save `myApp.server.port=8020` in `application.properties`, it will work fine.

To register a custome property file, you can annotate a `@Configuration` class with the additional `@PropertySource` annotation:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:custom.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:another.properties")
public class ConfigClass {
   // Configuration
}
```

make sure, your class path is correct.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. This is what I am already doing but it does not load this. Also I need to get this initialized so that port can be assigned to Tomcat server before start of Tomcat server.

Comment: Why dont you use `application.propertues` file to configure port. You can easily type `server.port=8020`

Comment: I tried to show how to use `$value` for an example.